# Spock framework only one exception condition is allowed per 'then' block

Tags: groovy, spock

```
org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4
Gradle 2.4
Groovy 2.3.10
```

I am using gradle and spock framework to test my java code. However, the function I am testing can throw 3 different exceptions that I need to test for. However, in my `then` clause I list the 3 exceptions and if any of them are not thrown the test will pass. However, I keep getting the following compile error:

```
318: Only one exception condition is allowed per 'then' block @ line 318, column 9.
           notThrown NoResponseException

319: Only one exception condition is allowed per 'then' block @ line 319, column 9.
           notThrown NotConnectedException
```

My spock function I am using for testing. The function being tested can throw those exceptions.

```
   def 'Create instant pubsub node'() {
       setup:
        smackClient.initializeConnection(domain, serviceName, resource, port, timeout, debugMode)
        smackClient.connectAndLogin(username, password)

        when:
        smackClient.getSPubSubInstance(smackClient.getClientConnection()).createInstantnode()

        then:
        notThrown XMPPErrorException
        notThrown NoResponseException
        notThrown NotConnectedException
    }
```

Is there a way to test for more than 3 exceptions in a single `then` clause?

I have also tried this which didn't work either by separating into 3 individual then clauses.

```
then:
notThrown XMPPErrorException

then:
notThrown NoResponseException

then:
notThrown NotConnectedException
```

Comment: Are other exception types acceptable?  If not, you can use noExceptionThrown().

Comment: @BillJames I used your suggestion combine with Gereth Davis answer.

Comment: unrelated to your concrete issue, but Gradle 2.4 is based on Groovy 2.3, which is why you should use version 1.0-groovy-2.3 of Spock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best I've come up with is use a `where:` clause

```
def 'Create instant pubsub node'() {
   setup:
    smackClient.initializeConnection(domain, serviceName, resource, port, timeout, debugMode)
    smackClient.connectAndLogin(username, password)

    when:
    smackClient.getSPubSubInstance(smackClient.getClientConnection()).createInstantnode()

    then:
    notThrown exception

    where:
    exception << [XMPPErrorException, NoResponseException, NotConnectedException]
}
```

I've created a [simpler example](http://meetspock.appspot.com/script/5735735550279680) on the [spock web console](http://meetspock.appspot.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I used your solution combined with @Bill James.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to check multiple `notThrown` statements in a single (or even multiple - when chained) - `then` blocks. As @BillJames commented you can use `noExceptionThrown` or the solution (just a curiosity - I don't find it useful nor readable) I prepared:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
    def sc = new SomeClass()

    def 'spec 1'() {
        when:
        sc.someMethod()

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()
    }

    def 'spec 2'() {
        when:
        sc.someMethod()

        then:
        notThrown(e)

        where:
        e << [E1, E2, E3]
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    def someMethod() {
    }
}

class E1 extends RuntimeException {}
class E2 extends RuntimeException {}
class E3 extends RuntimeException {}
```